# What does ${file?my.file.txt} and ${file:?my.file.txt} mean in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell

When I read some tutorial today, I came over with the statements like `${file?my.file.txt}` and `${file:?my.file.txt}`, what do `${file?my.file.txt}` and `${file:?my.file.txt}` mean in Bash script?

Comment: For your future questions, please do a little research before. I've seen you've asked a bit about Bash in particular, but your questions are hardly based on an actual problem and somewhat lack demonstration of research effort.

Comment: @slhck Ok. In fact, I just wanna know the specific details. Sorry for that if it conflicts with the style here. Thanks for the patient answers, anyhow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) – and it's always good to check that first:

> ```
> ${parameter:?word}
> ```
>
> If `parameter` is null or unset, the expansion of `word` (or a message to that effect if `word` is not present) is written to the standard error and the shell, if it is not interactive, exits. Otherwise, the value of `parameter` is substituted.

So, it's a safeguard against unset variables, where you  could show an error. Also,

> Omitting the colon results in a test only for a parameter that is unset. Put another way, if the colon is included, the operator tests for both parameter’s existence and that its value is not null; if the colon is omitted, the operator tests only for existence.

But of course, the examples you gave are somewhat arbitrary and I wonder why the tutorial would even include them, let alone including them but not explaining what they do.

Comment: After I make all these things clear, I will write a really high quality doc. Thx!